# GetSharedPreferences get session id

Tags: java, android

i have a get Shared Preference in login user id , adapters java access but fail red line show on `getActivity()`.

adapters.java code

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.siparisitemlayout,parent,false);
    getSharedPreferences = new GetSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    kurye_id=getSharedPreferences.getSession().getString("id",null);
     return new ViewHolder(view );
}
```

[image: adapters code fail image]

getsharedprefences code

```
public GetSharedPreferences(Activity activity)
{
    this.activity=activity;
}

public SharedPreferences getSession()
{
    sharedPreferences = activity.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("",0);
    return  sharedPreferences;
}

public void setSession(String id,String username)
{
    sharedPreferences = activity.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("id",id);
    editor.putString("username",username);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use there `getActivity()`....Use `context`.

Change your code like this:

```
 getSharedPreferences = new GetSharedPreferences(context);
```

First also check that:GetSharedPreferences class have parameterised contructor for activity?

**Get SharedPreferences string value from adapter**

Pass the context of the calling activity in your adapter through constructor and then use that context :

```
  Context context;
    public ConversationsAdapter(Context context,ConversationsAdapter.ConversationOnClickHandler conversationOnClickHandler) {
       this.context=context;
       mConversationOnClickHandler = conversationOnClickHandler;
    }
```

Now in your adapter you can do this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("my_preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String id= preferences.getString("id_key", "default_value");
```

Comment: thx for help but gave the same error red line context

Comment: See my answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329190/get-sharedpreferences-string-value-from-adapter/57329710#57329710

Comment: edit my code shared prefences

Comment: GetSharedPreferences class how to convert context ?

Comment: Post your GetSharedPreferences code here

Comment: question edit post I gave the code

'public GetSharedPreferences(Activity activity)
{
    this.activity=activity;
}

public SharedPreferences getSession()
{
    sharedPreferences = activity.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("",0);
    return  sharedPreferences;
}

public void setSession(String id,String username)
{
    sharedPreferences = activity.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("id",id);
    editor.putString("username",username);
    editor.commit();
}'

Comment: public GetSharedPreferences(Context contex)
try this

Comment: You can also pass activity inside adapter and use that...its second option.

Comment: SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("my_preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String id= preferences.getString("id_key", "default_value");  try but always default value return

Comment: Whenever you try to get value ->inside getSharedPreferences("",0),write your preference name.In my example there is ""my_preference" name .

Comment: Check this link for global class of sharedpreference.There is one PrefManager.java class.Refere this link:https://abhiandroid.com/programming/shared-preference